# Resolving a formatter string

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following:

```
format.string <- "@AB@-@BC@/@DF@" #wanted to use $ but it is problematic
value.list <- c(AB="a", BC="bcd", DF="def")
```

I would like to apply the value.list to the format.string so that the named value is substituted. So in this example I should end up wtih a string: `a-bcd/def`

I tried to do it like the following:

```
  resolved.string <- lapply(names(value.list), 
       function(x) { 
         sub(x = save.data.path.pattern, 
             pattern = paste0(c("@",x,"@"), collapse=""),
             replacement = value.list[x]) })
```

But it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `glue` package is designed for this. You can change the opening and closing delimiters using `.open` and `.close`, but they have to be different. Also note that `value.list` has to be either a list or a dataframe:

```
library(glue)

format.string <- "{AB}-{BC}/{DF}"
value.list <- list(AB="a", BC="bcd", DF="def")

glue_data(value.list, format.string)
# a-bcd/def
```

Comment: love this solution!

Comment: Isn't this using a different string than the OP's original code

Comment: @akrun Sure, but from what I can tell, OP was just trying to substitute whatever is inside the delimiters with `value.list` regardless of what the delimiters are. This is implied by his comment "#wanted to use $ but it is problematic"

Comment: @avid_useR yup, you are correct. This was just a sample. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, by using `lapply` over `names(value.list)` you, as your output shows, take each of the elements of `value.list` and perform the replacement. However, all this happens independently, i.e., the replacements aren't ultimately combined to a single result.

As to make something very similar to your approach work, we can use `Reduce` which does exactly this combining:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) sub(paste0(c("@", y, "@"), collapse = ""), value.list[y], x),
      init = format.string, names(value.list))
# [1] "a-bcd/def"
```

If we call the anonymous function `f`, then the result is

```
f(f(f(format.string, "A"), "B"), "C")
```

exactly as you intended, I believe.

Comment: Good to know for future use! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsubfn` that can take a key/value pair as replacement to change the `pattern` with the 'value'

```
library(gsubfn)
gsub("@", "", gsubfn("[^@]+", as.list(value.list), format.string))
#[1] "a-bcd/def"
```

NOTE: 'value.list' is a `vector` and not a `list`

Comment: I updated the question a little. Is there a way to not use [A-Z] because my named vector is actual names.

Comment: @Denis I changed the pattern based on the example.